# Paste transposed data to new row

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I am trying to create a form in excel in Sheet 1 (named Form) where the data copied from Sheet 1 (Form) is pasted to Sheet 2 (Data).

The form is vertical; however, the data is horizontal.

As such, I am using PasteSpecial.

When I use the macro button to paste and clear the data from the "Form" to the "Data", it is works for the first and second use. On the third use, the data is pasted on the second set of data rather than in a new row.

```
Sub Submit()  
    '  
    ' Submit Macro  
    '  

    '  
    Range("C2:C14").Select  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Data").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
      :=False, Transpose:=True  
    Range("A3").Select  
    Sheets("Form").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.ClearContents  
    Range("C2").Select  
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. The form is set vertically. That is from up to down. whereas the data where it is supposed to be pasted is from left to right. I need transpose for that.

Comment: refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub Submit()

Sheets("Form").Range("C2:C14").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to find out how to avoid using Select/Activate.

Comment: Yes.  
I replaced `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
            :=False, Transpose:=True  
        Range("A3").Select`
with `Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True`